# I want a sidebar and the main container with their own scrollbars

Tags: reactjs, typescript

in my react App I have a main page with the following structure

```
<Layout>
   <Header />
   <Aside />
   <Main />
</Layout>
```

I want to have the `<Aside/ >` and the `<Main />` components to have their own scrollbars but I don't find any way to do this.

I gave both components the css style `overflowY: 'scroll'` property but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Both components need the following css properties:

```
position: 'sticky',
height: `calc(100vh - ${headerHeight}`),
overflowY: 'scroll'
```